# How to render radio button group with the jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using jQuery DataTables and need a way to render a radio button on  a column in a datatable, this render must be through the JavaScript and not from JSON result.

Comment: Please show your code, ie how you initialise the datatable and the JSON you want to transform to radio buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

You can use [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to produce content for a cell.

Consider the following example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1us28',
    order: [[1, 'asc']],
    columnDefs: [
        { 
            targets: 0,
            searchable: false,
            orderable: false,
            render: function(data, type, full, meta){
               if(type === 'display'){
                  data = '<input type="radio" name="id" value="' + data + '">';      
               }

               return data;
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wa7fodzh/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: How to get selected radio buttons values of all datatable pages? I want to get all selected radio buttons values of each page  let suppose in an array

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan, [answered your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46217809/3549014).