# Datatables:Trying to get selected radio buttons values of each table row in csv format

Tags: jquery, csv, datatables

I am using jquery datatable plugin. What I am trying to do is to get all selected radio button values in CSV (comma separated values) format. As there are too many records, pagination is using.

When I select radio buttons on the first page, I can get all selected radio buttons values in CSV. It's working fine. When I go to second page and select radio buttons, the problem here occurs. I am getting all selected radio buttons on the second page but then first-page radio buttons value vanish. Similarly, I am getting the third page selected radio buttons values but then the second page selected values are gone and so on... I have attached an image for more elaboration:

[image]

In short, I am trying to get selected radio button values of all pages (or on those pages where user select radio buttons) in CSV format.

Following jquery code I am using to get selected radio button values:

```
  var StateIDs = $('.status:checked').map(function() { 
      return this.id; 
  }).get().join(',');
```

Is there any datatable API method to get this work done?

Answer (score 1):

#### CAUSE

Elements from page other than first don't exist in DOM, that is why `$()` jQuery method can't access radio buttons from other pages.

#### SOLUTION

Use jQuery DataTables [`$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) API method that gives you access to all elements in the table.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var StateIDs = table.$('.status:checked').map(function() { 
   return this.id; 
}).get().join(',');
```

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: How to submit all pages form data](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-submit-all-pages-form-data) for more information.

Comment: Ok let me try that , will inform you if it works . Thank you for your response.

Comment: I have not test it, shifted to some other work , As i test it, will response you.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fiddle for you check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Manoj1991/h2m1vg29/65/)

```
$('.select-first').on('change', function(e) {
   alert("Checked");
   var options = $(this).prop("checked", true);
   var checked = 'id='+ ids + '&option='+ options;
}); $('#myTable').DataTable();
```